# python use bound method of a class created by string variable

Tags: python, methods

I have a possible stupid question regarding python so forgive me in advance.
I have the following class in the file check.py in the folder checks:

```
class Check(object):
  def __init__(self): 
    print "I am initialized"

  def get_name():
    return "my name is check"
```

And this class is loaded through a variable string with the following function:

```
def get_class( kls ):
  parts = kls.split('.')
  module = ".".join(parts[:-1])
  m = __import__( module )
  for comp in parts[1:]:
      m = getattr(m, comp)            
  return m
```

I have my reasons to create a class defined by a string variable so don't try to circumvent this.

Now when I run the following:

```
from checks import *  # the __init__.py is correct of this one
s="check"
cl=get_class("checks."+s+"."+s.title())
a=cl()
print str(a)
print "name="+str(a.get_name)
```

I get the following output:

```
I am initialized
<checks.check.Check object at 0x0000000002DB8940>
name=<bound method Check.get_name of <checks.check.Check object at 0x0000000002DB8940>>
```

Now my question: is there any way that I can access the Check.get_name method? So I can get the result "my name is check"?

`

Comment: You accidentally omitted the `(self)` argument in `Check.get_name`, so it got created as a staticmethod instead of an ordinary method. That's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `Check.get_name` definition:

```
class Check(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "I am initialized"

    def get_name(self):
        return "my name is check"
```

Then you can access it with the following code:

```
from checks import *  # the __init__.py is correct of this one
s="check"
cl=get_class("checks."+s+"."+s.title())
a=cl()
print a.get_name()
```

Comment: Thank you! If feel so stupid for asking this question right now but I was stuck for more than an hour on this issue...